# Anonymous user edit the answer

Tags: discussion

I have found answer of one [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36159/can-i-modify-guestbook-module-safely/36161#36161) in which an answer was edited by anonymous user and the post was totally changed.

I think, there should not be *edit* access to anonymous user.

[image: drupal edit]

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous editing is allowed all over the network; we don't get that much edits to need to disable them, considering that rejecting an anonymously suggested edit would have the same result as with other suggested edit: When X suggested edits are rejected, the user is not allowed to suggest further suggested edits. In the case of anonymous users, I am not sure if the IP is considered or what, but the effect is surely the anonymous user not being able to suggest more edits.

If all, I would block those edits that change too much of the original post; I am sure I made a feature request over at Meta Stack Overflow, the network-wide meta site.

Comment: OK.. I have also _rejected_ that post edit.